# Can I mapping with mapstruct a class that extends from ArrayList<Object>?

Tags: java, arraylist, mapstruct

Have a problem trying to mapping a Object that extends from Arraylist into a Class that have a List, my code is:

1. First Class, this extends from ArrayList:

```
public class ClassOne extends ArrayList<ClassTwo> {}
```

2. I need mapping into:

```
public class ClassTarget {
    private String companyId;
    private List<ObjectTarget> fieldListTarget;
}
```

When I declare the mapper the error is:

```
java: Can't generate mapping method from iterable type to non-iterable type.
```

I think that the error is in `extends ArrayList<SomeObject>` I don´t know how can I mapping fields with this type of object.

Comment: If you provide an example of how you expect the mapping to look like I would be able to help you out better

Answer (score 0):

`Iterable` is an Interface, that a class can implement. An `ArrayList` implements that, and with that indirectly also your class `ClassOne`. Have you tried to change your class to

```
public class ClassTarget implements Iterable {
    ...
}
```

and implement the necessary methods?